# publishing azure function - can you create a template json resource file

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions

I have an Azure function that needs an automated deployment script.  We currently have a line in the Powershell script that looks like this:

```
#create resources defined in JSON - 
az deployment group create --resource-group TESTGROUP --template-file resources.json
```

This is what the resource file has for the function name:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "functionapp_name": {
            "defaultValue": "[concat('widgets-',uniqueString(resourceGroup().id))]",
            "type": "String"
        }
```

This code works fine but I don't want to use dynamic function names anymore.  What I'm trying to accomplish is the following:

- if local.settings.json exists, then I want to call the function name by the developer's machine hostname
- if there is no local.settings.json file then i know this is for a prod env so I want to use different value.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
$file = 'path\to\local.settings.json'
$functionAppName = 'nameToGiveYourFunctionAppIfInProd'

#If the file exists, use dev machine hostname.
if (Test-Path -Path $file -PathType Leaf) {
     $functionAppName = [System.NET.DNS]::GetHostByName('').HostName
}

#Now run your az deployment script and pass the funcAppName as parameter

#create resources defined in JSON - 

az deployment group create --resource-group TESTGROUP --template-file resources.json --parameters functionapp_name=$functionAppName
```